# Using wire:poll to show progress in processing items in a loop (progress indicator/progress bar)

Tags: laravel, progress-bar, laravel-livewire

I'm working on an app that processes a bunch of items (submitted by a user) in a loop.  The processing takes time and I want to show the progress to the user.  I'm trying to use `wire:poll` to regularly update the page as the processing occurs, but the reported number of items to process does not update until the loop is complete.

Here's a minimal version of what I have tried, with `sleep(1)` replacing the method that does the processing.

Livewire component:

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class ProcessItems extends Component
{
    public $numberProcessed = 0;

    public function process()
    {
        for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
            sleep(1);
            $this->numberProcessed++;
        }
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.process-items', [
            'number' => $this->numberProcessed,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Blade:

```
<div>

    <form method="POST" wire:submit="process()" method="POST">
    <div class="pt-4">
        <x-primary-button class="ml-0">
            {{ __('Submit') }}
        </x-primary-button>
    </div>
    </form>

    <div wire:poll>
        Items processed: {{ $number }}
    </div>

</div>
```

After pressing the Submit button, processing starts, but despite the `wire:poll` the `$number` remains 0 until the loop finishes, when it jumps to 10.  So it seems that Livewire is not "seeing"  the updates to `$this->numberProcessed` that occur within the loop.

How do I get `$number` to update regularly (`wire:poll` is supposed to update every 2.5 seconds by default)?

Or is this whole approach wrong?

Comment: Poll is intended to automatically call the backend to update periodically the page of the browser. It can only wait the backend execution and get the result. Possible (complicate) solutions: **1** the backend stops execution after a number of operations, saves his state and returns the control to the frontend, saying that must be called again, it will start from the saved state (slower execution) **2** the backend starts a new process that goes on its own, storing in a persistent storage the progress, the backend queryes the progress and reports it to  the frontend (risk to loose the control)

Comment: @Pippo Thank your for your clear explanation and suggestions.  Suppose that instead of using `wire:poll`, I take a different approach: I dispatch an event in each iteration of the loop by adding `$this->dispatch('update-number-processed', numberProcessed: $this->numberProcessed)` after the line `$this->numberProcessed++` in the `process` method of the component, and listen for those events in the Blade file by using `$wire.on('update-number-processed')`.  Do those events also get dispatched only after the loop is complete?  (That's what my tests suggest.)

Comment: Yo can try, but I suppose that the events are all sent at the end of the elaboration along with the results